# Spark write.avro creates individual avro files

Tags: apache-spark, avro

I have a spark-submit job I wrote that reads an in directory of json docs, does some processing on them using data frames, and then writes to an out directory.  For some reason, though, it creates individual avro, parquet or json files when I use df.save or df.write methods.

In fact, I even used the saveAsTable method and it did the same thing with parquet.gz files in the hive warehouse.

It seems to me that this is inefficient and negates the use of a container file format.  Is this right?  Or is this normal behavior and what I'm seeing just an abstraction in HDFS?

If I am right that this is bad, how do I write the data frame from many files into a single file?

Comment: This is a normal behavior. Each worker is processing and writes its own part of the data.

Comment: But now I have thousands of small avros which seems to negate the value of the metadata on the name node.  I thought avro or sequence files had their own metacontent so we could store small chunks or blocks within the container of the avro instead...or am I wrong about this?

Comment: More likely you're doing something not exactly right on the way. Very large number of partition typically result from lack of control of number of partitions. The crude solution is to `coalesce` your data before writing.

Comment: Three facts you must be aware of: **1.** Hadoop has been designed for **massive batch jobs**, not for the kind of jerk-one-record-at-a-time stuff you appear to be doing **2.** HDFS files are **immutable** *(well, actually, nowadays you can Append or Truncate them but these are edge cases and Spark carefully avoids these cases)* **3.** for CSV files you can use the "Hadoop archive" trick to reduce the NameNode pressure *(that's a kind of transparent TAR format)* but it won't work for the elaborate "container" file formats you mention *(although ORC has a Stripe Merge trick of its own)*

Comment: Samson, this actually is a big batch job, but because of the nature we had to orchestrate between scripting and nifi for ingest (instead of Sqoop) which deposits thousands of JSON into HDFS.  The Spark-Submit job reads this input dir into a data frame and then saves the data product down (hopefully) as a single parquet.  We are considering spark-streaming with kafka, but are very BIG batch driven for now (croned spark-submit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As **@zero323** told its normal behavior due to many workers(to support fault tolerance).

I would suggest you  to write all the records in parquet or avro file which has avro generic record using something like this

```
 dataframe.write().mode(SaveMode.Append).
   format(FILE_FORMAT).partitionBy("parameter1", "parameter2").save(path);
```

but it wont write in to single file but it will group similar kind of Avro Generic records to one file(may be less number of medium sized) files

Comment: yes, your answer did exactly what I wanted, including adding _metadata to the root dir.  Thank you.

Comment: Ram, actually, just looked again and I noticed a duplication of results.  Now when I read in the root dir as sqlContext.read.parquet() I get a duplicate row for every entity.  Looking into the partitioned dirs I see file identifiers duplicated.  Any idea why this might be?

Comment: If you implement it correctly, ideally it should not have duplicates.pls. revisit  your logic. if needed you can use hash functions like mumurhash to avoid duplicates